# SQL Server messages system with conversation list

Tags: sql-server, whatsapp, message

Good morning!

I have developed a web application to allow people to exchange messages.

I use SQL Server 2008 and Classic ASP on Windows 2012 Server.

To simplify, suppose there are only 2 tables:

```
tUsers
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
  Username VARCHAR(20)

tMessages
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
  UserIdFrom INT
  UserIdTo INT
  SentDate DATETIME
  Message VARCHAR(300)
  Read TINYINT
```

My question is simple, but I can't find a solution specific for MS SQL.

I need to write a query that returns the conversation list between me and other users I talked with.

The list must contain *UserId* and *Username* (not mine but of the users I talked with) and must be in reverse order by sent date/time order, and must include the message (from or to me) without answer (as Whatsapp for example).

I found many solutions, but for MySQL the conversion to MS SQL is not working. This is the first time I need help on SQL, but I can't find a solution by myself.

Can anyone give me an example of T-SQL query to solve my problem???

Sorry for my English, I used to speak Italian.

This is my second question on StackOverflow. I hope I have respected the rules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a query which works in MySql it would be good to include that in your question - there should not be much change to MSSQL

Comment: SQLFiddle gives me an error when create table... can I use IDEONE.COM instead? For you is the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.Id,
       t2.Username,
       m.SentDate,
       m.Message
FROM tMessages m
INNER JOIN tUsers t1
    ON m.UserIdFrom = t1.Id
INNER JOIN tUsers t2
    ON m.UserIdTo = t2.Id
WHERE (t1.Username = 'danylele'   AND t2.Username = 'yourFriend') OR
      (t1.Username = 'yourFriend' AND t2.Username = 'danylele')
ORDER BY m.SentDate DESC
```

If you want to user ID instead of username, you can just use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (t1.Id = 'yourId'   AND t2.Id = 'friendId') OR
      (t1.Id = 'friendId' AND t2.Username = 'yourId')
```

Comment: @Jamiec Updated my query.  Hoping this won't lead to an endless exchange of comments, possibly including a downvote along the way.

Comment: This does not get the entire conversation list between me and all other users I talk to and I need to use my UserId and not Username in the query.

Answer (score 0):

With a H/T to @Tim you can take his query, and union it with the opposite in order to get messages to *and* from another person:

If you wish to retrieve a list of all *conversations you have had you could use a query such as

```
DECLARE @myUserId INT = 1
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Username 
FROM
(
  SELECT t2.Id,
       t2.Username,
       m.SentDate,
       m.Message
  FROM tMessages m
  INNER JOIN tUsers t1
    ON m.UserIdFrom = t1.Id
  INNER JOIN tUsers t2
    ON m.UserIdTo = t2.Id
  WHERE t1.Id = @myUserId 
  UNION
  SELECT t2.Id,
       t2.Username,
       m.SentDate,
       m.Message
  FROM tMessages m
  INNER JOIN tUsers t1
    ON m.UserIdFrom = t1.Id
  INNER JOIN tUsers t2
    ON m.UserIdTo = t2.Id
  WHERE t2.Id = @myUserId
)
ORDER BY SentDate DESC
```

If you want all the messages in a specific conversation use:

```
DECLARE @myUserId INT = 1
DECLARE @friendUserId INT = 2
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT t2.Id,
       t2.Username,
       m.SentDate,
       m.Message
  FROM tMessages m
  INNER JOIN tUsers t1
    ON m.UserIdFrom = t1.Id
  INNER JOIN tUsers t2
    ON m.UserIdTo = t2.Id
  WHERE t1.Id = @myUserId AND t2.Id = @friendUserId   
  UNION
  SELECT t2.Id,
       t2.Username,
       m.SentDate,
       m.Message
  FROM tMessages m
  INNER JOIN tUsers t1
    ON m.UserIdFrom = t1.Id
  INNER JOIN tUsers t2
    ON m.UserIdTo = t2.Id
  WHERE t1.Id = @friendUserId AND t2.Id = @myUserId
)
ORDER BY SentDate DESC
```

Comment: Careful: Your ordering might not survive the `UNION` intact.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep, that was careless.

Comment: I need to get the entire list of my conversations, not only with one users, like Whatsapp chat list, with all users I talk with. Your SQL seem to get only one user (specified with friendUserId).

Comment: @danylele - you might want to review your question. `I'd like to write a query that returns the conversation list, for example between me and other user I talked to.`

Comment: @Jamiec - the first query doesn't work... SMS result is Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant debug code your for you. If you want me to, set up a http://www.sqlfiddle.com with your table structure and some sample data

Comment: @Jamiec -I try with SQL Fiddle... I never use it but I try.

Comment: @Jamiec - when I try SQLFiddle setting MS SQL Server 2008 It say me "Create script error" but if I set MySQL the CREATE TABLE script works.